# How to access W and W' matrices in Gensim Word2Vec in negative sampling setting?

Tags: python, gensim

Are these `model.wv.vectors` and `model.trainables.syn1neg`? And will they be similar after enough runs?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the `wv.vectors` and `syn1neg` arrays correspond to the weights described as *W* and *W'* elsewhere.

But, they won't necessarily become similar after training. (If that was the ideal end-point, they could just be assigned to the same values!)

Rather, they serve different roles, and aren't usually compared after model training finishes. Only the "input"/"projection" vectors are what are commonly referred-to as word2vec word-vectors.

Mitra et al at Microsoft Research have observed that the hidden-to-output weights (`syn1neg`) can be useful for some purposes, in their "[Dual-Embedding Space Model](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/project/dual-embedding-space-model-desm/#!publications)" write-ups.  But, I've not noticed these negative-sampling layer vectors being used much.